# Easy way to find unused lines in a JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I have a webpack' generated *build.js* file that is about 5Mb in size and I would like to find which lines are unneeded so that I can erase them **directly from the *build.js* file**.

Note that I **can't** remove unneeded modules (i.e. `npm-check-unused`) and then re-build again the project. I need to be able to "observe" which lines are never hit. As in some sort of *post-build* optimization from a *third-person observer*. **How can I do this?**

Comment: This _might_ be a better fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What you're asking for is a pretty complicated tool. It's very hard to look at a bunch of JavaScript code and determine what parts will never be used, because the language is so dynamic. Anyway, if you're building a Node application, transmission time should not be a concern; loading 5 megabytes of JavaScript on a modern computer does not consume a significant amount of time. A tool like Uglify is probably the safest and simplest approach.